# Encontrar coincidencias e igualdades entre dos arrays de objetos

Tags: javascript

deseo comprar dos arrays de objetos y obtener los objetos que se repiten en ambos arrays y tambien los objetos que solo estan en uno de los dos arrays de momento tengo esto:

```js
const coincidencias  = []
const soloEnNuevas   = []
const soloEnActuales = []

    const frutasNuevas = [
        {
          idFruta: '1001',
          nombreFruta: 'Mango'
        },
        {
          idFruta: '2003',
          nombreFruta: 'Durazno'
        }
    ]

    const frutasActuales = [
        {
          idFruta: '1001',
          nombreFruta: 'Mango'
        },
        {
          idFruta: '3004',
          nombreFruta: 'Uva'
        },
        {
          idFruta: '5002',
          nombreFruta: 'Fresa'
        }
    ]

    for(const frutaNueva in frutasNuevas) {
      const {idFruta, nombreFruta} = frutasNuevas[frutaNueva];
        console.log(nombreFruta)
        for(const frutaActual in frutasActuales){
        const {idFruta, nombreFruta} = frutasActuales[frutaActual];
          console.log(nombreFruta)
        }
    }
```

Y deseo llegar a este resultado:

```
  coincidencias: [ { idFruta: '1001', nombreFruta: 'Mango' } ]

  soloEnNuevas: [ { idFruta: '2003', nombreFruta: 'Durazno' } ]

  soloEnActuales: [
    { idFruta: '3004', nombreFruta: 'Uva' },
    { idFruta: '5002', nombreFruta: 'Fresa' }
  ]
```

Espero me puedan ayudar y guiar para lograr el objetivo planteado, quedo atento y muchas gracias por la atención prestada

Answer (score 1):

Con `for` es un poco complicado obtener ambas partes, ya que pdrías llegar a obtener las que se repiten, pero el problema es que para que funcione con las que solo están de un lado o de otro, tendrías que empezar a iterar con el `array` más grande o guardar aquellas frutas que no han sudo repetidas e irlas sacando, lo que aumentaría la complejidad.

Una solución más sencilla es hacer el map de los `ids`

```
const frutasActualesId = frutasActuales.map((fruta) => fruta.idFruta);
const frutasNuevasId = frutasNuevas.map((fruta) => fruta.idFruta);
```

Después de eso filtras los elementos que no estén el ciertos ids

`coincidencias` tiene que ser el array de `frutasNuevas` cuyos `ids` están en los `ids` de `frutasActuales`

```
const coincidencias  = frutasNuevas.filter((fruta) => frutasActualesId.includes(fruta.idFruta));
```

`soloEnNuevas` tiene que ser el array de `frutasNuevas` cuyos ids no están en los `ids` de `frutasActuales`

```
const soloEnNuevas   = frutasNuevas.filter((fruta) => !frutasActualesId.includes(fruta.idFruta));
```

`soloEnActuales` tiene que ser el array de `frutasActuales` cuyos ids no están en los `ids` de `frutasNuevas`

```
const soloEnActuales = frutasActuales.filter((fruta) => !frutasNuevasId.includes(fruta.idFruta));
```

Ejemplo completo

```js
const frutasNuevas = [
  {
    idFruta: '1001',
    nombreFruta: 'Mango'
  },
  {
    idFruta: '2003',
    nombreFruta: 'Durazno'
  }
]

const frutasActuales = [
  {
    idFruta: '1001',
    nombreFruta: 'Mango'
  },
  {
    idFruta: '3004',
    nombreFruta: 'Uva'
  },
  {
    idFruta: '5002',
    nombreFruta: 'Fresa'
  }
]

const frutasActualesId = frutasActuales.map((fruta) => fruta.idFruta);
const frutasNuevasId = frutasNuevas.map((fruta) => fruta.idFruta);
const coincidencias  = frutasNuevas.filter((fruta) => frutasActualesId.includes(fruta.idFruta));
const soloEnNuevas   = frutasNuevas.filter((fruta) => !frutasActualesId.includes(fruta.idFruta));
const soloEnActuales = frutasActuales.filter((fruta) => !frutasNuevasId.includes(fruta.idFruta));

console.log(coincidencias);
console.log(soloEnNuevas);
console.log(soloEnActuales);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y orientación, definitivamente es mucho mejor de lo que tenia pensado, gracias por ayudarme y hacerme crecer!

Answer (score 0):

javascript cuenta con dos functiones de filtro que funcionan para los arrays, una es filter() y la otra es find() las cuales reciben un callback que debe retornar true o false, el item  que llegara a esa funcion sera el elemento que se este iterando en el momento.

filter() retorna una lista de los elementos que cumplan la condicion, si no se encuentra ninguno el default sera [] un array vacio

filter() en cambio, retornara la primera coincidencia que encuentre, de no encontrar ninguna su default sera undefined o null.

puedes usar filter para buscar dentro de las frutasNuevas los elementos que su id ya se encuentre dentro de la lista de frutasActuales, algo como:

```
const coincidencias = frutasNuevas.filter(x=> frutasActuales.find(y => y.idFruta == x.idFruta) != null)
```

y para las soloNuevas podrias simplemente cambiar la condicion:

```
const soloNuevas = frutasNuevas.filter(x=> frutasActuales.find(y => y.idFruta == x.idFruta) == null)
```

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico en la respuesta. Dices `filter() en cambio, retornara la primera coincidencia que encuentre`  cuando te estás refiriendo a **find()** en lugar de **filter()**. Saludos!